# Show that $(W_t, \int_0^t W_s ds)$ has a normal joint distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, normal-distribution

I have to show that, if $W_t$ is a 1-d Brownian motion then 
$\biggl(W_t, \int_0^t W_s ds\biggr)$ has normal distribution.
Hint: apply Ito formula to this bivariate process. 
Any idea or suggestion on how to solve it?

I tried to show that with characteristic function approach, since the marginal distributions have both normal distribution

If I want to show that the couple is bivariate gaussian I have to prove that:
$$\forall \lambda_1 , \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}:  Z_t=\lambda_1 W_t + \lambda_2 \int_0^t W_s ds \ \text{ is normal} $$

$dZ_t = \lambda_1dW_t+\lambda_2W_tdt$ and if I compute $\phi_{Z_t}(\eta)$ and $d(\exp{i\eta Z_t})$, then in the end I get:
$$\phi_{Z_t}(\eta)=\int_0^t \mathbb{E}(\exp{(i\eta Z_s)} \cdot i\eta\lambda_2 W_s)ds-\int_0^t \mathbb{E}(\phi_{Z_s}) \cdot \eta^2 \cdot 1/2 \cdot ds$$
and I don't know how to solve the first integral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t W_s ds &= tW_t -\int_0^t sdW_s \tag{1}\\
&= \int_0^t (t-s)dW_s.
\end{align*}
Then, for $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 W_t + \lambda_2 \int_0^t W_s ds &= \lambda_1\int_0^t dW_s + \lambda_2 \int_0^t (t-s)dW_s\\
&=\int_0^t \big(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2(t-s)\big)dW_s,
\end{align*}
which is normal.